# EU National - Can I present an EU ID to register in Switzerland?

Tags: resident-permit, eu-citizens, switzerland

I am an EU national (Italy) moving soon to Switzerland to work. I will need to register with the cantonal authorities. The issue is that I don't have the passport (only an ID card) and it's not possible to obtain one in time (I've already verified this).

Can I register + get work permit with a European ID card and not the passport? My contract is internship, lasts for around 5 months.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The [agreement between Switzerland and the EU concerning the free movement of persons](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02002A0430%2801%29-20210101&qid=1643178158817) effectively includes Switzerland in the free movement system of the EU and EEA.  In particular, it provides for the use of a national ID card in place of a passport.

Note, however, that there are some differences.  For example, you will need a work permit because your contract is longer than three months.  Some PDF "factsheets" are [available on the website of the State Secretariat for Migration](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta/eu-efta_buerger_schweiz/factsheets.html), also [in Italian](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/it/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta/eu-efta_buerger_schweiz/factsheets.html).

For further confirmation, you'll want to check the website of the canton where you'll be working (the federal secretariat has a [list](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/sem/kontakt/kantonale_behoerden/adressen_kantone_und.html)).  For example, Geneva's application form asks for *une pièce d'identité* rather than *un passeport.*

To be clear, if you're not using a passport, you must use a national ID card that states your nationality.  Other forms of identification, such as driver's licenses, are not sufficient.

Comment: Article 6,12,20 (3)(a): *the document by virtue of which he entered their territory;* ; Article 1 (1): *...to enter their territory simply upon production of a valid identity card or passport.*